# GeoEvent Processor for Server Service Stopping

Tags: arcgis-server, geoevent-processor

I have recently began using the GeoEvent Processor for server, It will run for one minute and then stop. I can't really intepret the logs to see what the problem is, and I am hoping a better eye than mine can help me out. The log is from when I started the service to when it failed.

http://pastebin.com/M63dWcDW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your license is invalid.  See the line in the log:

2014-10-30 16:39:10,196 | ERROR | rint Extender: 3 | LicenseEnforcer                  | 333 - com.esri.ges.rest.cxf-service - 10.2.1 | Our license isn't valid.  Shutting down.

Comment: Thank you, how did I miss that. I solved it by running setup as administrator. Thank you!